# Plugin init function executed more than once

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

To test a service method, I'm executing it in my init function. The method adds a row to the database table with a mail address and variant id:

```
$this->waitingListService->add(7, 'email@mailserver.com');
```

However, when I refresh a page in the control page to execute the plugin init function 2, or sometimes 3 rows are being added to the database table.

Is this the default behaviour and if not, how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `init` function should only trigger once for each instance. So when you do something like `new Plugin` it is executed multiple times.

But keep in mind that it is executed in **every** request. So when you are in the CP there are many different ajax calls (every time when you reload entries at the index page for example). You'll create a new row for each of those requests

In order to disable your function you can check

```
$request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
if (!$request->getIsAjax() && !$request->getIsConsoleRequest()) {

}
```